# iOS calendar week events view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, uicollectionview

For my application I have to develop a view that displays the events of a calendar in a Week View, just like the landscape view of the iPhone calendar app.

I was thinking about using a CollectionView but I don't know if is possible to have the content of the cell continuing in another cell, in the case of an event covering multiple hours, like this example, in which the description can continue trough multiple cells:

[image: Event covering multiple hours]

Is there any plugin I can use to create this view?

Comment: Hi there - I don't know how Calendar is implemented, but it strikes me that it would be much simpler to just have one cell for each day rather than a cell for each hour? Then each appointment in a day can be constructed as a subview with the frame positioned (using a bit of maths) to cover the time interval in question. Essentially, this then becomes a graph plotting problem!

Comment: have you find any solution?

Comment: @h-raval I've developed a custom solution, it was the only way. I've started from a basic UIScrollView, then added a subview for every grid, and above it a subview for each event, calculating the X & Y positions based on the hours/day of the week